# Как мне сохранить все то что было в терминале

Tags: python

```
def create_cards():
    print("Можешь писать новые карты")
    new_card = input()
    cards.append(new_card)


while True:
    create_cards()
    print("Добавлять дальше или уже все? F - ЗАКОНЧИТЬ, T - ПРОДОЛЖИТЬ")
    ex = input()
    if ex == "T":
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Как мне сделать так что бы все что я ввел в терминале осталось в массиве cards

Comment: Судя по вашему коду, оно и так остаётся. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cards = []
def create_cards():
    global cards
    print("Можешь писать новые карты")
    new_card = input()
    cards.append(new_card)


while True:
    create_cards()
    print("Добавлять дальше или уже все? F - ЗАКОНЧИТЬ, T - ПРОДОЛЖИТЬ")
    ex = input()
    if ex == "T":
        continue
    else:
        break
```